# Why is the object not visible while I am moving it - only the origin is shown?

Tags: interface

I don't know what I did but now when I click on the blue arrow to move the object up the object stays where it is and the origin moves until I release the mouse button.  Then the object shows its new location. Is there some setting I accidentally turned off or on that does this? The same thing happens for any manipulation of the object (scale, rotation, moving).

[image: Gizmo shows fine before I click and drag]
[image: Only the origin moves until I release the mouse button]

Comment: maybe you've enabled the Transform > Affect Only > Origin in the Options (top right of the 3D view)?

Comment: @moonboots But the ojbect did moved as said in the question.

Comment: do you have a physic simulation or animation going on for this object?

Comment: Thanks for the tips and your time. I checked 'Affect Only Origin' and it was ok. And i did have a cloth simulation attached. But I am pretty sure it wasn't running. I also saved and reopened the file to see if that helped - it didn't. So I just started a new file and all is well now - I was hoping to discover what I did wrong so i dont do it again.

Comment: it's probably the cloth sim (would have been my first question) if there is any data in the cache, it will try to utilize it and sort of ignore your changes until you rebake or restart. Going to frame 1 should solve that.